# FileSystemWatcher and unprocessed files

Tags: c#

I am using the FileSystemWatcher to notify when the new files gets created in the network directory. We process the text files(about 5KB size) and delete them immediately when the new file gets created in the directory. If the FileSystemWatcher windows service stops for some reason we have to look for the unprocessed files after it gets back up and running. How can I handle if the new file comes while processing the old files from the directory? Any examples please?

Thank you,

Here is the code example I have with simple form.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private System.IO.FileSystemWatcher watcher;
    string tempDirectory = @"C:\test\";
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CreateWatcher();
        GetUnprocessedFiles();
    }
private void CreateWatcher()
{
    //Create a new FileSystemWatcher.
    watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    watcher.Filter = "*.txt";
    watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName;
      //Subscribe to the Created event.
    watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(watcher_FileCreated);
    watcher.Path = @"C:\test\";
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}

void watcher_FileCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    //Parse text file.
       FileInfo objFileInfo = new FileInfo(e.FullPath);
        if (!objFileInfo.Exists) return;  
        ParseMessage(e.FullPath);
}


  void ParseMessage(string filePath)
  {
       // Parse text file here 
  }

  void GetUnprocessedFiles()
  {
      // Put all txt files into array.
    string[] array1 = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\test\"); 
    foreach (string name in array1)
    { 
        string path = string.Format("{0}{1}", tempDirectory, name)
        ParseMessage(path);
    }
  }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

When the process starts do the following:

- first get the contents of the folder
- process every file (end delete them as you already do now)
- repeat until no files are in the folder (check again here, since a new file could have been placed in the folder).
- start the watcher

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I thought about it.

Comment: While unlikely, this is not a good solution. A file could be created between your last check for files and the watcher being initialized.

Answer (score 1):

For any of our services that use the FileSystemWatcher we always process all the files that exist in the directory first, prior to starting the watcher.  After the watcher has been started we then start a timer (with a fairly long interval) to handle any files that appear in the directory without triggering the watcher (it does happen from time to time).  That usually covers all the possibilities.